# Exclude blank/FALSE cells in in Excel array IF formula output

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I am having difficulties with making an array formula work the way I want it to work.

Out of a column of dates which is not sorted, I want it to extract values into a new column. The formula below identifies the required cells of a given month and year, but they appear in their original row rather than on top of the output range. Moreover, I want all ""/FALSE cells to be excluded from the output array.

```
=IF((MONTH($I$15:$I$1346)=1)*(YEAR($I$15:$I$1346)=2008),$I$15:$I$1346,"")
```

In fact, the $I$15:$I$1346 should be dynamic and go to the last filled range (I could make a named range for that)

Part two is to expand on that formula so that it calculates the data that is an two column offset of the data described above.

Is the above possible to build into one cell probably with a combination of IF, INDEX, SMALL and maybe others?

I'm not looking for a filter solution. Hope the above is clear enough and that you can help!

Here's a shortened sample layout:

```
    A           B          C
1   Date        Series_A   Series_B
2   03/01/2011  45         20
3   04/01/2011  73         30
4   06/01/2011  95         40
5   08/01/2011  72         50
6   06/02/2011  5          13
7   09/02/2011  12         #N/A
8   05/02/2011  23         65
9   07/03/2011  12         65
```

Then I want three input cells for the year and and the month and series name (index/match, as there are many more columns with data). If it would be 2011, Feb and Series_A, I want it to calculate the average for that month. In this case it would be (5+12+23)/3. If it would be Feb-2011 and Series_B instead, which has an error, it should show (13+65)/2 rather than an error.

Aside from that I want a separate which will output an array with the data instead without 'holes' in between and with the right 'length'. Example for Feb-2011 in Column C:

```
    A           B          C                  D
1   Date        Series_A   Desired Output     Output based on f above
2   03/01/2011  45         5                  
3   04/01/2011  73         12
4   06/01/2011  95         23
5   08/01/2011  72         
6   06/02/2011  5                             5
7   09/02/2011  12                            12
8   05/02/2011  23                            23
9   07/03/2011  12
```

If I then run a =ISBLANK(C5) it should be true, rather than =""=C5

Hope the edit clarifies

Comment: Can you post a sample row of data and the desired output? That would make it easier to understand your problem.

Comment: I have amended the initial post. Should be clear now

Comment: That helped, but it is still clear as mud. I _think_ you are looking for something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614923/excel-formula-identifying-number-of-date-ranges-within-a-range/14616697#14616697 . Take a read through that and let us know if that helps or is similar to what you are looking for. The "second part" is still pretty unclear...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not really what I am looking for. Identifying the correct cells based on year and month is easy using IF((MONTH($a$2:$a9)=2)*(YEAR($a$2:$a$9)=2008),$a$2:$a$9,""). Problem is that the the output then comes out like in Column D (see post) rather than column C. This is due to the fact that the array is replicated and the IF statement just switched the cells not matching the criteria with "". I believe getting a formula that would generate an output as in column C would be step 1, and then altering it to give averages should be simple.

Comment: I have uploaded a file explaining part 1. Link should work for 24h atleast. http://www.fildump.se/?file=tmp_199672031411362742817-array_problem.xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to various platsforms to get an answer, and here you have one which is ok. Still doesn't fully answer part 1, but works nonetheless.

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/905356-exclude-blank-false-cells-in-in-excel-array-if-formula-output.html