# match index getting #n/a when Vlookup produces a result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can run a `vlookup` on something and can get an answer.  When I go to run it as an *index/match* I get `#N/A`

I'm doing an index on a date.  I go to see if the dates are equal and they are not.  I don't know how to massage the dates to get them to match?  They look the exact same.  I've tried to format them the exact same to no avail.

Can someone give me advice?  I've already tried adding `+0` to `B26` and that didn't work.

```
=INDEX('sheet2'!B13:B20,MATCH(B26,'sheet2'!D13:D20,0))
```

Why am I switching to *index/match* when my `vlookup` works fine?  Because the dates I'm searching on will be in the same month in year but not exact day.  I thought I would use *index/match* to ultimately find the month/year and pull in the data that way.

Comment: Are you using the right columns? If you are matching in D and returning a value from B you wouldn't be able to use VLOOKUP anyway.......or do you have a different setup for the VLOOKUP version?

Comment: For a more complex approach to what you are doing, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614923/excel-formula-identifying-number-of-date-ranges-within-a-range/14616697#14616697 . I thought it might give you a few ideas!

Comment: I have a different set up for the VLookup, which returns the correct value.  It's something in the format of the dam dates that Index/Match is having a hard time with.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new column with a string made up of parts of the date and MATCH based on that. It's possible that you are not using VLOOKUP with the last parameter set to "false", so it is giving you the nearest result, not an exact match, and when you switch to index/match, it's no longer finding the nearest value.

For example, you could have the column (let's say E) contain

```
=YEAR(B13)&"-"&MONTH(B13)
```

And then use:

```
=INDEX('sheet2'!B13:B20,MATCH(YEAR(B26)&"-"&MONTH(B26),'sheet2'!E13:E20,0))
```